# iOS XCode 6 NSTimer does not stopping by means of invalidate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I would like to know what's is wrong with this codes :

```
IBOutlet UIImageView sam1;
IBOutlet UIImageView sam1;
NSTimer *timer1;
NSTimer *timer2;


-(void)start {
    [self performSelector:@selector(myTimer1) withObj....
}

-(void)startAlso {
    [self performSelector:@selector(myTimer2) withObj....
}

-(void)myTimer1 {
    timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimeWithInterval .....
}

-(void)myTimer2 {
    timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimeWithInterval .....
}

-(void)specialFuct {
     [timer1 invalidate];
     [timer2 invalidate];
}
```

Desc of my program is a simple game using imageview.
each imageview has their own NSTimer since they are both moving.

when 2 imageview collides, their timer is stop using invalidate.

my problem is, 2 imageview is coming from center.y -40 which is
outside the screen layout.

when the 2 imageview is inside the screen, it stops.
but when it is still outside the screen, -40 let say.

their NSTimer is still moving which is causing me a bug.

is their any explanation of why is this happening?

thank you in advance! first time xcoder here.

**UPDATE!**

I already found the problem,

it is on the

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(myTimer1) withObj....
```

part.

What's happening is, the NSTimer is already shutdown but the performSelector delay is still runnning. My alternative way is to have a boolean and check if the game is already over or not.

```
if(gameOverIsNotOver) {
     [self performSelector:@selector(myTimer1) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}
```

is there any best way to do this? thanks in advance!

Comment: is your `specialFuct ` ever called?

Comment: yes, if 2 objects collide, it is called. then the 2 objects' NSTimer should stop.

Comment: check for sure you just init `timer1/timer2` one time. And `specialFuct` called after `myTimer1`

Comment: Don't use perform selector (though you can cancel that too)...

Comment: Why are you using performSelector? Seriously? Did you dig out some 20 year old sample code? Do yourself a favour and learn about Grand Central Dispatch and dispatch_after.

Comment: We don't know whether timer1 and timer2 are local variables, global variables, instance variables, or whatever, so there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: I am really sorry guys. As what I written above, it is my first day to use XCode.. don't be too harsh on me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have awful description with dots in code. But hope my answer will help and solve your problem.
If you create scheduled `NSTimer` you can call `invalidate` to cancel its action.
For `performSelector` you can call:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

And it will cancel all future selectors with delay for this (`self`) class.

Better don't use selectors and timers together. Global variables - is a bad pattern too.

Comment: for the performSelector, I use it to call my NSTimer.
I add some afterDelay so my game with be more randomized.
Sorry it is my first time to use xcode.